# How to pass a variable and a list in a lisp function

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Apologies if this is a beginner question. Harsh comments are welcome. I am learning LISP and got a snippet like the below. It checks a constant value in a list and returns only the elements greater than it.

```
(defun greaterthanX (l)
  (if l
    (if (> (car l) 5)
      (cons (car l) (greaterthanX (cdr l)))
      (greaterthanX (cdr l))
    )
  )
)

(print(greaterthanx '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 3)))

Output : (6 7 8)
```

**My question is how do I pass a variable inside the recursive function and modify it instead of passing a constant value (ie. 5 in the above case)?**

I am looking for something like this :

```
(defun greaterthanX (x l)
  (if l
    (if (> (car l) x)
      (cons (car l) (greaterthanX (cdr l)))
      (greaterthanX (cdr l))
    )
  )
)

(print(greaterthanx '5 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 3)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you would additionally pass the `x` value in the two recursive calls to `greaterthanX`:

```
CL-USER 5 > (defun greater-than-x (x l)
              (if (consp l)
                  (if (> (first l) x)
                      (cons (first l)
                            (greater-than-x x (rest l)))
                    (greater-than-x x (rest l)))))
GREATER-THAN-X

CL-USER 6 > (print (greater-than-x 5 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 3)))

(6 7 8)   ; printed
(6 7 8)   ; repl output
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want the recursion to have to pass down the value, then you use an a local function:

```
(defun keep-greater-than (x l)
  (labels ((rec (l)
             (if l
                (if (> (car l) x)
                  (cons (car l) (rec (cdr l)))
                  (rec (cdr l))))))
    (rec l)))
```

The local function `rec` accesses the outer function's parameter `x`, which is visible to it.

Comment: This is a very common pattern. I do this for almost every recursive function that I write. +1

Answer (score 0):

Also `greater-than-x` is nothing else than `filter`:

```
(defun greater-than-x (x l)
  (filter (lambda (el) (< x el)) l))
```

Or a typical `reduce` function. `filter` you can express als `reduce`:

```
(defun my-filter (fun l)
  (nreverse 
    (reduce (lambda (result el) 
              (if (funcall fun el)
                  (cons el result)
                  result))
            l :initial-value '())))
```

or recursion:

```
(defun my-filter (fun l &optional (acc '()))
  (cond ((null l) (nreverse acc))
        ((funcall fun (car l)) (my-filter fun (cdr l) (cons (car l) acc)))
        (t (my-filter fun (cdr l) acc))))
```